# ImageIO can only write PNGs, fails for other formats (with no errors reported)

Tags: java, javafx

With the following methods:

```
  @FXML
  public void exportSideImage() {
    File imageLocation = ImageExport.display();
    WritableImage image = SideView.getInstance().snapshot(null, null);
    BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
    try {
      ImageIO.write(bImage, getFileExtension(imageLocation), imageLocation);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private String getFileExtension(File file) {
    String name = file.getName();
    int lastIndexOf = name.lastIndexOf(".");
    return name.substring(lastIndexOf + 1);
  }
```

my program will only write an image if a "png" image is specified. I've tested this on multiple platforms (Linux, Windows) but the issue persists. Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check the result code from ImageIO.write => it can report false, and also print the file extension to confirm that it is one of the set:

```
ImageIO.getWriterFileSuffixes()
```